# Implementing side menu for iOS App, app crashing on gestures to present.

Tags: ios, swift, side-menu

I am trying to implement side menu for my iOS app, using this library https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu 
By code implementation, below the code written in view did load func:

```
    let menuRightNavigationController = UISideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: SideMenuViewController())

    SideMenuManager.default.menuRightNavigationController = menuRightNavigationController
    SideMenuManager.default.menuFadeStatusBar = false

    SideMenuManager.default.menuAddPanGestureToPresent(toView: self.navigationController!.navigationBar)
    SideMenuManager.default.menuAddScreenEdgePanGesturesToPresent(toView: self.navigationController!.view)
```

But the Application is crashing on last two lines of the above code, and the below code written in button action:

```
    @objc func menuButtonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    present(SideMenuManager.default.menuRightNavigationController!, animated: true, completion: nil)    
}
```

Guys please help to handle the crashing so I can present my side menu. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share crash logs?

Comment: Is your application embed with navigation controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your app crashes when it runs into `nil` value in this line: 
`SideMenuManager.default.menuAddPanGestureToPresent(toView: self.navigationController!.navigationBar)`, however without a crash log I can only make some assumptions.

I am assuming the `self` here refers to `UIViewController` class. According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) the `navigationController` property is The nearest ancestor in the view controller hierarchy that is a navigation controller. This property is nil if the view controller is not embedded inside a navigation controller.

I would recommend you to make sure you initiate the UINavigationController object before you force-unwrap it. Here is [useful documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller), which may help you get the concept of navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks, I have embed in Navigation controller to my view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your a line of code from this

```
SideMenuManager.default.menuAddPanGestureToPresent(toView: self.navigationController!.navigationBar)
```

to this

```
SideMenuManager.default.menuAddPanGestureToPresent(toView: self.view)
```